JsonStreamWriter() fails with {0=Field root.Context failed to convert to JSON. Error: JSONObject does not have a string field at root.Context
Trying to write a JSON column to a BigQuery JSON column using the JsonStreamWriter() in the Storage API which fails with:
com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.Exceptions$AppendSerializationError: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Append serialization failed : 
**{0=Field root.Context failed to convert to JSON. Error: JSONObject does not have a string field at root.Context.}**

root.Context is a JSON field in itself which I like to store in a BQ JSON column directly. As I use JSONStreamWriter() the complete payload is a JSON so the the "Context" JSON field is nested inside the JSON payload which might be the problem? Is it possible to use JSONStreamWriter() for this or what do I do wrong?
My payload in JSON looks like:
[
    {
        "Context": {
            "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; el-GR; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100922 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.10",
            "Ip": "<REDACTED>"
        },
        "Channel": "browser",
        "STREAMER_DEPLOYMENT_ID": "<REDACTED>",
        "STREAMER_THREAD_NUMBER": 1,
        "Timestamp": "2024-10-01T11:57:37.567002Z",
        "SentAt": "2024-10-01T11:57:37.566997Z",
        "STREAMER_RUN_ID": "<REDACTED>",
        "Type": "identify",
        "Version": "1.1",
        "STREAMER_CLIENT_TIME_MS": 1727783857698,
        "STREAMER_BATCH_NUMBER": 0,
        "AnonymousId": "<REDACTED>",
        "STREAMER_INSTANCE_NUMBER": 0,
        "STREAMER_OFFSET": 0,
        "ReceivedAt": "2024-10-01T11:57:37.566945Z",
        "MessageId": "<REDACTED>"
    }
] 

converted to protobuf (debugging only as I use JSONStreamWriter which do the conversion for me):
message SomeMessage {

    message _context {
        string _user_agent = 1;
        string _ip = 2;
    }

    message Nested {
        _context _context = 1;
        string _channel = 2;
        string _s_t_r_e_a_m_e_r__d_e_p_l_o_y_m_e_n_t__i_d = 3;
        uint32 _s_t_r_e_a_m_e_r__t_h_r_e_a_d__n_u_m_b_e_r = 4;
        google.protobuf.Timestamp _timestamp = 5;
        google.protobuf.Timestamp _sent_at = 6;
        string _s_t_r_e_a_m_e_r__r_u_n__i_d = 7;
        string _type = 8;
        string _version = 9;
        uint64 _s_t_r_e_a_m_e_r__c_l_i_e_n_t__t_i_m_e__m_s = 10;
        uint32 _s_t_r_e_a_m_e_r__b_a_t_c_h__n_u_m_b_e_r = 11;
        string _anonymous_id = 12;
        uint32 _s_t_r_e_a_m_e_r__i_n_s_t_a_n_c_e__n_u_m_b_e_r = 13;
        uint32 _s_t_r_e_a_m_e_r__o_f_f_s_e_t = 14;
        google.protobuf.Timestamp _received_at = 15;
        string _message_id = 16;
    }

    repeated Nested items = 1;
}

and finally my table looks like:
CREATE TABLE TEST.EVENTS (
    STREAMER_THREAD_NUMBER INT,
    MESSAGEID STRING(255),
    STREAMER_BATCH_NUMBER INT,
    STREAMER_INSTANCE_NUMBER INT,
    STREAMER_OFFSET BIGINT,
    STREAMER_CLIENT_TIME_MS INT,
    CONTEXT JSON,
    ANONYMOUSID STRING(255),
    CHANNEL STRING(255),
    RECEIVEDAT STRING(255),
    TIMESTAMP STRING(255),
    SENTAT STRING(255),
    USERID STRING(255),
    VERSION STRING(255),
    STREAMER_RUN_ID STRING(255),
    STREAMER_DEPLOYMENT_ID STRING(255),
    TRAITS JSON,
    TYPE STRING(255),
    INTEGRATIONS JSON,
    PROPERTIES JSON,
    EVENT STRING(255),
    ORIGINALTIMESTAMP STRING(255)   
);

Thanks for all help!

This is because the JSONStreamWriter is designed to serialize a single JSON object into a stream, not nested objects. Your root.Context is a nested object, causing the JSONStreamWriter to fail.
Probably you can try to flatten the JSON array first, this way you ensure that each object is treated as separate row in BigQuery.

do we know if StreamWriter supports nested JSON (proto) objects? I can't find any references for JSONStreamWriter or StreamWriter describing those  limitations.

As far as I know handling nested JSON objects requires specific serialization logic, which is not included in StreamWriter. You'll need to use dedicated libraries for this purpose.
